# Compare field to see if it changed from yesterday until today

Tags: sql, oracle, date, lag

I need to see records where the COMP_DATE changed or as added from yesterday and only show records that changed. I need to see if someone changed the value.

I've tried LAST_VALUE and LAG but I can't seem to get the comparison right.

Example Data:

```
Date          JOB    COMP_DATE
SYSDATE -1   1       09-01-2017

SYSDATE      1       09-27-2018
```

---

```
SELECT

   JOB, COMP_DATE,

   LAST_VALUE(COMP_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY JOB ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Last_Value

    FROM  JOB_TABLE

   *** I know this section is not valid ***

    Where LAST_VALUE <> Current COMP_DATE
```

Comment: So do you want to know if a specific record has changed since yesterday, or all records that changed since yesterday?

Comment: Are there really only 3 columns in this table and does it not have a primary key? Is this table basically a "log"? There are many options....

Comment: is that first "date" column you're mentioning a real column or is it just you listing an action that was taken. If it's not a real column, then you may have to use flashback query, if it's available.

Comment: I'm trying to find all records that were changed since yesterday. There are a lot of columns but the rest do not matter . The JOB would be the Primary Key. The table does not have a daily date filed. I was using the SYSDTAE as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a subquery.

```
select * from (
    SELECT
        JOB, 
        COMP_DATE,
        LAG(COMP_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY JOB) AS Last_Value
    FROM JOB_TABLE
) t1
where  LAST_VALUE <> COMP_DATE
```

Comment: Thank You. This does show the change but it doesn't specify when it was changed. Is there a way to say whether it was changed yesterday?

Comment: why are you using last_value and lag when the data is not there... I think the only way to get this will be using flashback query.

Answer (score 1):

First part will get changed records, the part after the union all will get new records.. assuming I'm interpreting your table structure correctly. Although you might have to put "'s around the "date" field name.

```
 select * from job_table j1
  join job_table j2 on j2.job_id=j1.job_id and j2.date = j1.date - 1
 where 
 j1.comp_date != j2.comp_date
 and j1.com_date=sysdate;
 union all
 select * from job_table j1 where not exists (select * from job_table j2
    where j1.date != j2.date and j1.job_id=j2.job_id)
```

Comment: This is a real cluster. I think this would work if my tables had a daily DATE field. My sample is misleading.

Comment: When you say "real cluster", are you referring to "RAC" or cluster f**k.. sorry I really can't tell.

Comment: I just meant it was complex. Since I do not have a date field in my table would it be possible to use a timestamp or other date function?

Comment: Have you read up on flashback query? That's going to be the way to do it if you have access to it. If you do, I'll write an answer using flashback query. Also, my opinion that any solution using "lag" or "last_value" is going to be barking up the completely wrong tree-- couldn't possibly work using those functions if I'm understanding your situation properly.

Answer (score 1):

The result using flashback query (note, the "as of timestamp" needs to be "yesterday" in your example-- might get away with using sysdate -1, but I cannot get on oracle right now to test.

This will tell you that it was changed between yesterday and now, but with no greater precision than that.

```
 select j1.comp_date, j2.comp_date, j1.job_id
   from job_table j1
   left outer join job_table j2 
     as of timestamp('2018-09-28 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
     on j1.job_id=j2.job_id
   where j2.comp_date is null or j2.comp_date != j1.comp_date
```

Comment: Thank you Joe.  I currently do not have sufficient privileges to run the As Of Timestamp command but this is very useful. I will see if I can get access.

Comment: When you pay for an expensive DB like Oracle, you need to use the unique features it has to be worth it.